# Most "statistically sound" method for finding the average of multiple different metrics

Tags: mean, geometric-mean, harmonic-mean

If I have 3 different metrics and I wanted to find an "average" (not necessarily arithmetic mean) of the 3 metrics so that observations can be ranked, what would be the most "statistically sound" method of doing so?

Here's an example with baseball:

I have 3 metrics:

- Batting Average (ranges from `0.000` to `0.350`)
- Home Runs (ranges from `0` to `50`)
- RBI (ranges from `0` to `120`)

And I want to equally weight each metric and take some sort of average so that I can rank different players, with the best players being great in all 3 metrics.

If I wanted to "average" the metrics so that each metric has equal weight, I could:

- Standardize each metric so they're all on the same scale and calculate the arithmetic mean
- Calculate the geometric mean
- Calculate the harmonic mean

Is 1 of these methods more/less "statistically sound" than the others, in terms of not violating any assumptions or anything of the like?

Comment: "Statistical soundness" doesn't apply.  The right way to combine multiple metrics depends on subjective factors that statistics (alone) cannot determine.

Comment: @whuber thanks for marking this as a duplicate -- I didn't come across that question in my search. Much appreciated.

Comment: No need to apologize--it is hard to search for something when there is no evident set of keywords to look for!  I am glad that you appreciate the value of finding a relevant pre-existing post--not all new contributors understand that.